# Accessing page in different folder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have this line in one my views in my home folder

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ResearcherID })
```

When I click it will take me to Home/Edit/id

However my Edit page is located in Researchers/Edit

I tried doing:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Researchers","Edit", new { id = item.ResearcherID })
```

but it took me to this page instead http://localhost:12345/Home/%20Researchers?Length=4

How can I link to my desired page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The researchers edit page is part of the `Researchers` controller. Specify the `Edit` action on the `Researchers` controller in your `ActionLink()` call.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Researchers", new { id = item.ResearcherID }, null)
```

[LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29)

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Works perfectly now.

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Researchers",null, new { id = item.ResearcherID }) 
just directed to researchers/edit

Comment: @Viktor Make sure to accept the answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

if this Researchers is controller 
try this : @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit","Researchers", new { id = item.ResearcherID })